# How to ssh from centos 6.4 into a docker container without a password?

Tags: ssh, docker, centos

I have a CentOS 6.4 instance.

On this instance I can not ssh with a RSA key into a Docker container which is based from CentOS 6.7.

On Ubuntu (Trusty) and Amazon Linux instances I can ssh into the Docker container.

I need to use the ssh command (really ansible) and not `docker exec`.

The command I'm running is `ssh -i id_rsa -p 2200 user@localhost`.

My Dockerfile looks as so:

```
From centos:6.7

#update yum repository and install openssh server 
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN yum install -y sudo

RUN useradd user

RUN echo "user  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir -p /home/user/.ssh
ADD id_rsa.pub /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown user /home/user/.ssh -R
RUN chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

#generate ssh key 
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

EXPOSE  22
CMD ["sh","-c","/usr/sbin/sshd -D;sleep 1"]
```

I've already checked permissions on all files (private and public keys, authorized_keys) and directories (/.ssh).

The fact that I can ssh on amazon Linux to this container makes me believe that the issue does not come from my docker container nor permissions on files and folders.

I've changed the PAM on the Docker container and in the local CentOS.

I've updated Python to 2.7.12 (because this is really for ansible ... whatever).

The container is running.

I've removed known_hosts.

Played with ssh config.

When adding `-vvvvv` to my `ssh` command I get this issue:

```
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /path/to/project/dir/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common problems on the server side are:

1. permissions on the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys should be 400 / 600 (permissions on the owner only).
2. PAM security can be an issue, you should disable the PAM sshd_config.
3. the user that will "enter" the server (e.g centos) must be enabled (appear on /etc/shadow).
4. RSA should be enabled on the sshd_config.

solutions:

1. as the user sshing into (e.g. **centos**@server):

   `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. as root:

   `sed -i 's/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   service sshd reload`
3. for user "centos" (change if needed):

   `passwd -u -f centos`
4. as root:

   `sed -i 's/RSAAuthentication no/RSAAuthentication yes/g
   service sshd reload`

---

on the client side, just remember to hand out the key and the key should have 600 permission too. e.g.:
`ssh -i myrsa.key centos@server`

Comment: I added this to my Dockerfile: `RUN sed -i 's/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN yum install  passwd  -y
RUN passwd -f -u centos`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your host:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

sed -i 's|#AuthorizedKeysFile|AuthorizedKeysFile|g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's|.ssh/authorized_keys|%h/.ssh/authorized_keys|g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```